# Flutter: Route context is always pointing to the widget it is being routed - I want it to have context of Parent widget

Tags: flutter

To Simplify the problem,

1. I have 'App' with routes that includes route 'Page target (screen)'
2. I also use push() to navigate to 'Target Page' from a page called 'Listview'
3. I have a callback in 'Target page' to "App" that sends some data.

Now the problem is When I Navigate to 'Target Page', I can use callback properly
But When I Navigate from 'Listview' to 'Target Page', I callback throws the Error
"Called on NULL".

I know (with my minimal knowledge) this is happening because it routed from the 'ListView', Because Listview (of course) does not have that mentioned callback.

What I need is either a way to route to 'Target Page' that contains Parent context or
any other efficient way of sending data to App (parent).

[image: Widgets flow]

Hope this is clear.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the context of a particular widget, wrap it's child/children to Builder widget and gave them as builder. It will take a new context belonging to the parent and pass it down.